# How to remove contfoot, conthead, caption in longtblr package

Tags: latex

I want to remove `contfoot`, `conthead` and `caption` in `tabularray` package (I used `longtblr`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}%font mặc định
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,right=2cm,left=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%font a4
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}%TẠO BOOKMARK PDF
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%ngôn ngữ time new roman
\usepackage{titlesec}%chinh section
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{0}\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing\section{0}{0pt}{0pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%căn đều 2 bên
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\small\thepage}
\begin{document}
 \section*{DANH SÁCH NGƯỜI MỪNG PHONG BÌ CƯỚI SƠN - DIỄM}
\noindent
\begin{longtblr}{width=1\linewidth,rowhead=1,hlines,vlines,
 colspec={X[1,c]X[4,l]X[2,c]X[2,c]X[2,c]}, 
 colsep=6pt,
 rowsep=3pt,
 rows={1.5cm,m},row{1}={font=\bfseries,c}}
 STT&Tên người& {Số tiền\\(Nghìn đồng)}&Ngày xưa có đi không&Đi bao nhiêu\\
 1& Chị Nhung Kd Phúc Yên&300\\
 2& Chị Nhàn Kd Tam Dương&300\\
 3& E Hiền Kd Sản Nhi&300\\
 4& Chị Nga Kd Phúc Yên&300\\
 5& Chị Vân Viện 9&500\\
 6& Chị Dung Vĩnh Tường&500\\
 7& Chị Hằng kd Phúc Yên&200\\
 8& Lương Quyết&1000&Có&500\\
 9& Chị Huyền Anh&1000\\
 10&Anh Hải Nội A&300& Có&300\\
 11&A Tùng Dương&500\\
 12&C Huyền KD&300\\
 13&A Thành KD&200\\
 14& Thiệu CVP&500\\
 15&Linh Chồn&300& Có&300\\
 16& Xuyến A1&200& Có \\
 17& Phượng A1& 200& Có\\
 18&Nguyệt A1&300&Có \\
 19&Đức Anh UB&200&Không \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
```

to redefine the templates.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}%font mặc định
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,right=2cm,left=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%font a4
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}%TẠO BOOKMARK PDF
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%ngôn ngữ time new roman
\usepackage{titlesec}%chinh section
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{0}\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing\section{0}{0pt}{0pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%căn đều 2 bên
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\small\thepage}

\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{longtblr}{width=1\linewidth,rowhead=1,hlines,vlines,
 colspec={X[1,c]X[4,l]X[2,c]X[2,c]X[2,c]}, 
 colsep=6pt,
 rowsep=3pt,
 rows={1.5cm,m},row{1}={font=\bfseries,c}}
 STT&Tên người& {Số tiền\\(Nghìn đồng)}&Ngày xưa có đi không&Đi bao nhiêu\\
 1& Chị Nhung Kd Phúc Yên&300\\
 2& Chị Nhàn Kd Tam Dương&300\\
 3& E Hiền Kd Sản Nhi&300\\
 4& Chị Nga Kd Phúc Yên&300\\
 5& Chị Vân Viện 9&500\\
 6& Chị Dung Vĩnh Tường&500\\
 7& Chị Hằng kd Phúc Yên&200\\
 8& Lương Quyết&1000&Có&500\\
 9& Chị Huyền Anh&1000\\
 10&Anh Hải Nội A&300& Có&300\\
 11&A Tùng Dương&500\\
 12&C Huyền KD&300\\
 13&A Thành KD&200\\
 14& Thiệu CVP&500\\
 15&Linh Chồn&300& Có&300\\
 16& Xuyến A1&200& Có \\
 17& Phượng A1& 200& Có\\
 18&Nguyệt A1&300&Có \\
 19&Đức Anh UB&200&Không \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that despite the instructions above, the counters for the tables keep incrementing. How can we prevent this?

Comment: @juliushuck Please ask a new question including a [mre] which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to set these parameters for one longtblr only?

Comment: @leparc If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: I was indeed hesitating because it is… quite the same question.

Comment: @leparc You can do that by defining a new theme (say it is called `MyTheme`) with all the modified templates (obviously you will need to change the templates name to something other than `default`) and adding the optional argument `theme = MyTheme` in the particular `longtblr` environment.